# ImportError: cannot import name 'dropout_edge' from 'torch_geometric.utils'

Tags: python, import, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I am doing some preprocessing of a dataset with torch_geometric. The error occurred when trying to run the following lines where `OneStepDataset` is a subclass of the torch_geometric.data.Dataset class

```
dataset_sample = OneStepDataset(OUTPUT_DIR, "valid", return_pos=True)
graph, position = dataset_sample[0]
```

The compiler traces to these lines in `C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric\data\dataset.py:197`

```
 if (isinstance(idx, (int, np.integer))
    194         or (isinstance(idx, Tensor) and idx.dim() == 0)
    195         or (isinstance(idx, np.ndarray) and np.isscalar(idx))):
--> 197     data = self.get(self.indices()[idx])
    198     data = data if self.transform is None else self.transform(data)
    199     return data
```

but it doesn't show the root line that caused this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'dropout_edge' from 'torch_geometric.utils' (c:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric\utils\__init__.py)
```

Comment: What version of `torch_geometric` are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's going on?

You mentioned in the comment that you use [PyTorch Geometric](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io) in version `2.2.0` – the error you posted, however, is from a different one. You can identify by going to [GitHub source with tag `2.2.0`](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/blob/2.2.0/torch_geometric/data/dataset.py#L239) – the line of the error is `239`. The last version, in which the error was in line `197` is `2.1.0` (see GitHub source with tag `2.1.0`). This version [does not include](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/modules/utils.html) the `dropout_edge` in `torch_geometric.utils`, as opposed to the `2.2.0`, [which does](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.0/modules/utils.html).

## What does it mean?

Apparently, there is some kind of package version mismatch. It could have happened because of installing and re-installing in different ways (e.g., through `pip` and `conda` at the same time) or even tampering with the library files manually. To know for sure, one would need to know a little more about your environment (e.g., an exact list of packages with their respective versions), the installation process and all the steps since then. It's probably not worth it, though.

## Suggestions?

A quick way would be to simply reinstall the package. That being said, if you have a problem of this nature, something is not right with the installation process, and it might not necessarily help.

My suggestion would be to try to use a fresh environment, install packages one-by-one (ideally, using the same package manager) and see if the issue persists. I see that you have the library install globally – next time try to use virtual environments to mitigate such issues, or be able to recover quickly. You can find more on this topic in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I tried using google colab and the error no longer exists.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to completely uninstall torch-geometric and its dependencies, it seems like they can't get uninstalled completely whenever I try reinstalling on the local environment.

Comment: @playerJX1 From my experience, `pytorch-geometric` has been a very tricky package both to install and remove. Ideally, you would try to run the uninstall procedure with the same package manager you installed it with. [This comment](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/issues/1841#issuecomment-730952349) from the `pyg` creator might help as well. If it does not help, try to remove folders manually (in your case `C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric\` and the ones corresponding with its dependencies). I can't guarantee it will help, though.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I solved the problem after discovering that I had to reopen my notebook which would have been using pyg 2.1.0, not the 2.2.0 version I would be importing elsewhere.

Comment: Glad you could resolve your issue!